# Value changes not showing after @mixin is defined

Tags: sass, mixins

I defined a @mixin with 4 properties, two of them, (font-fam and font-size) are being applied when I @include, but two (text-align and color) are not. Any help on why this is happening?

Here's the defined @mixin:

```
        @mixin important-text {
  font-family: vipnagorgialla;
  font-size: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(153, 245, 4);
}
```

And here's where I called it:

```
      footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: $mainColor;
  @include important-text();
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and all the 4 properties are working for me.

Comment: Jinu Kurian is there any reason you could think of why it may be getting overridden?

Comment: Do you mean the properties are not showing in the compiled css or just that your styles are not applied?

Comment: @ChadRoussel Check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Jinukurian7/c6s3n7eh/4/